# javassist ; is missing

Tags: java, bytecode, javassist

Could anyone tell what is wrong with my code ?
when using javassist to insert code , it show error "Caused by: compile error: ; is missing";
But I double check , there no ; missing at all. Is there some limitation of javassist here?

```
        ClassPool cp = ClassPool.getDefault();
        cp.importPackage("com.mysql.cj");

        CtClass cc = cp.get(clzname);
        CtMethod ms = cc.getDeclaredMethod(
                "execute");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("String sql = ((PreparedQuery) this.query).getOriginalSql();");
        sb.append("QueryBindings bindings = ((PreparedQuery) this.query).getQueryBindings();\n" +
                "        for (BindValue o : bindings.getBindValues()) {\n" +
                "            sql = sql.replaceFirst(\"\\\\?\", new String(o.getByteValue()));\n" +
                "        }");

        sb.append(
                "System.out.println( sql);");

        ms.insertBefore(sb.toString());
        byteCode = cc.toBytecode();
```

Comment: it's hard to visually parse those append lines, so if you comment out your append lines, do you still have a ; error? If so, you probably need to be showing us a different part of your code. Doesn't your error message point you to a  specific line?

Comment: I'd double check the escape sequences `(\"\\\\?\", ` - these things are easy to get wrong.

Answer (score 6):

The javadoc for insertBefore says:

https://www.javassist.org/html/javassist/CtBehavior.html#insertBefore(java.lang.String)

> Parameters: src - the source code representing the inserted bytecode.
> It must be a single statement or block.

So, wrap the code in curly braces so it is a single block.

Comment: After wrapping your code into curly braces , it still shows the same error.....   [source error] ; is missing

Answer (score 1):

I solved my bug by replacing the for loop.

It seems javaassit not support convient for loop, it has to be change it into for(int i= 0; i< lenth; i++) format;

And thanks to @kutschem , the code also need to be wrapped  by  curly braces.

```
ClassPool cp = ClassPool.getDefault();
        cp.importPackage("com.mysql.cj");

        CtClass cc = cp.get(clzname);
        CtMethod ms = cc.getDeclaredMethod(
                "execute");

        ms.insertBefore("{\n" +
                "            String sql = ((PreparedQuery) this.query).getOriginalSql();\n" +
                "            QueryBindings bindings = ((PreparedQuery) this.query).getQueryBindings();\n" +
                "            for (int i =0; i < bindings.getBindValues().length; i++ ) sql = sql.replaceFirst(\"\\\\?\", new String(bindings.getBindValues()[i].getByteValue()));\n" +
                "            System.out.println(sql);\n" +
                "        }");

        byteCode = cc.toBytecode();
```

Comment: The compiler within javassist is very simple, and with a lot of limitation. e.g. generics, vargs, (un/)boxing. See https://github.com/jboss-javassist/javassist/wiki/Tutorial-3

Answer (score 0):

In addition to wrapping your code into curly braces like *@kutschem* said, I also have an idea for you how to concatenate your string more easily, without using a `StringBuilder`. As a positive side effect, you also get line breaks:

```java
String codeToBeInserted = String.join("\n",
  "{",
  "  String sql = ((PreparedQuery) this.query).getOriginalSql();",
  "  QueryBindings bindings = ((PreparedQuery) this.query).getQueryBindings();",
  "  for (BindValue o : bindings.getBindValues()) {",
  "    sql = sql.replaceFirst(\"\\\\?\", new String(o.getByteValue()));",
  "  }",
  "  System.out.println(sql);",
  "}"
);
System.out.println(codeToBeInserted);
```

`String.join` is available since Java 8. The console output would be:

```java
{
  String sql = ((PreparedQuery) this.query).getOriginalSql();
  QueryBindings bindings = ((PreparedQuery) this.query).getQueryBindings();
  for (BindValue o : bindings.getBindValues()) {
    sql = sql.replaceFirst("\\?", new String(o.getByteValue()));
  }
  System.out.println(sql);
}
```

To me, your code looks okay syntactically, especially the `replaceFirst` meant to replace `?` by a fixed value.